# What is the correct Oracle syntax for nested selects referencing the same tables?

Tags: oracle, select, nested

I am trying to write a query but I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is correct.  The best way for me to explain this is to show you what I want and what I have

What I want:

```
   ID | SomeCol1 | SomeCol2 | Fish | Cat
   -------------------------------------
   1      foo        bar       baz   boz
   2      foo2       bar2      baz2  boz2
```

What I have:

```
select
  tblA.id as "ID", 
  tblB.someCol as "SomeCol1",
  tblD.someOtherCol as "SomeCol2"
from TableA tblA
inner join TableB tblB on tblA.fkId1=tblB.id
inner join TableC tblC on tblA.id=tblC.fkId2
inner join TableD tblD on tblC.fkId8=tblD.id
inner join TableE tblE on tblC.fkId9=tblE.id
```

This correctly gives me the first 3 columns.

This separate query gives me the correct column/values for 'Fish'

```
select tblE.someCol as "Fish"
from TableA tblA
inner join TableB tblB on tblA.fkId1=tblB.id
inner join TableC tblC on tblA.id=tblC.fkId2
inner join TableD tblD on tblC.fkId8=tblD.id
inner join TableE tblE on tblC.fkId9=tblE.id
where tblD.someOtherColumn = 'Fish';
```

I would make a similar one for cat, using the same tables.

However if I try to combine the queries by nesting the selects like so I would obviously get "The single-row subquery returns more than 1 row) error.

```
select
  tblA.id as "ID", 
  tblB.someCol as "SomeCol1",
  tblD.someOtherCol as "SomeCol2",
  (select tblE.someCol as "Fish"
    from TableA tblA
    inner join TableB tblB on tblA.fkId1=tblB.id
    inner join TableC tblC on tblA.id=tblC.fkId2
    inner join TableD tblD on tblC.fkId8=tblD.id
    inner join TableE tblE on tblC.fkId9=tblE.id
    where tblD.someOtherColumn = 'Fish'),
  (select tblE.someCol as "Cat"
    from TableA tblA
    inner join TableB tblB on tblA.fkId1=tblB.id
    inner join TableC tblC on tblA.id=tblC.fkId2
    inner join TableD tblD on tblC.fkId8=tblD.id
    inner join TableE tblE on tblC.fkId9=tblE.id
    where tblD.someOtherColumn = 'Cat')
from TableA tblA
inner join TableB tblB on tblA.fkId1=tblB.id
inner join TableC tblC on tblA.id=tblC.fkId2
inner join TableD tblD on tblC.fkId8=tblD.id
inner join TableE tblE on tblC.fkId9=tblE.id
```

So, how would I correctly do this?  Also is there a way to reference the tables only once instead of multiple time as shown above?  *My real-world query is more complex and has more tables to join and 15 or so columns that will have to perform the same logic as the 'Fish' column.

Thanks!

** UPDATE - I think I figured it out.  I need to create the subquery once using the 'with' command.  I then create subqueries off of that:

```
    with v_tbl as (
        select *
        from TableA tblA
        inner join TableB tblB on tblA.fkId1=tblB.id
        inner join TableC tblC on tblA.id=tblC.fkId2
        inner join TableD tblD on tblC.fkId8=tblD.id
        inner join TableE tblE on tblC.fkId9=tblE.id
    ), v_fish as (select name from v_tbl where tblD.someOtherColumn = 'Fish')
    , v_cat as (select name from v_tbl where tblD.someOtherColumn = 'Cat')
    select <regular query stuff>...
```

Comment: I'm unaware of any specific syntax but calling them `tblA...` looks extremely confusing.

Comment: I just named them that to make them easier to track for this demo.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't see why you need a subquery at all:

```
select
  tblA.id as "ID", 
  tblB.someCol as "SomeCol1",
  tblD.someOtherCol as "SomeCol2",
  tblE.someCol as "Fish"
from TableA tblA
inner join TableB tblB on tblA.fkId1=tblB.id
inner join TableC tblC on tblA.id=tblC.fkId2
inner join TableD tblD on tblC.fkId8=tblD.id
inner join TableE tblE on tblC.fkId9=tblE.id
where tblD.someOtherColumn = 'Fish';
```

Comment: I may have misspoke in my statements above.  The Fish column should only return values where the value is "Fish".  It should not return other values like Horse, Cat, etc...  The other 15 columns I mentioned may also reference the same table but look for Horse or cat. So the table is being re-used and a single filter like what is shown would prevent that

Comment: What about a straight inner join on A-E and then using a case statement, so you have as many statements as you need in the form case when tblD.someOtherColumn = 'Fish' then tblE.someCol else null end as "Fish". I don't know whether that would perform better or worse than your final version, but it's a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved it and posted the answer in the original post